# Query two keys from the same table with different relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has 2 relations with two other different tables.

```
User
id_user

Users_Licenses   (one-to-many unidirectional)
user(coach)
license_id

License
id
user_id (user simple) (one-to-one user)
```

Now I have to return the username of the user (one-to-one) or null if there is no one but I am not sure how to do that, because it always returns me the username of the coach.
What I've tried:

```
SELECT ul.license_id, u.username, cl.created_at
FROM user u
INNER JOIN users_licenses ul ON ul.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN license l ON l.id = ul.license_id
WHERE ul.user_id = :coachId
```

Comment: Which rdbms you use?

Comment: I am using MySql.

Comment: You can have a user-id without a corresponding user-entry? Or do you mean that there is a license but no user-license and no user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `LEFT OUTER JOIN` back to `USER`

```
SELECT ul.license_id, userLicensee.username as licensee
FROM user u
INNER JOIN users_licenses ul ON ul.user_id = u.id_user
INNER JOIN license l ON l.id = ul.license_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user userLicensee ON l.user_id = userLicensee.id_user
WHERE ul.coachid = :coachId
```

Note that i have also changed `WHERE ul.user_id = :coachId` to `ul.coachid = :coachId`(you have not mentioned the name of the foreign-key column for the coach-user).

Answer (score 0):

use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT ul.license_id, u.username, cl.created_at
FROM users_licenses ul
LEFT OUTER JOIN license l ON l.id = ul.license_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON ul.user_id = u.id
WHERE ul.user_id = :coachId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ul.license_id, u.username, cl.created_at
FROM user u, users_licenses ul, license l
where ul.user_id = u.id 
and  l.id = ul.license_id
and ul.user_id = coachId;
```

try to change the select statement to that:

Comment: I haven't tried your solution ut thank you for your response.